# fetch all topics from dbpedia

Tags: sql, json, sparql, dbpedia

How can I fetch all the topics from dbpedia in format like JSON, Spreadsheet or any other so that I can process on them later. Can I do this from this SPARQL console from dbpedia:

```
http://dbpedia.org/sparql
```

I am not familiar with SPARQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [information page](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess), it has some links to sample queries. One of those, for example, is for [The Beatles](http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Beatles). At the foot of that example query output page are links to various JSON versions of the data:

RDF: http://dbpedia.org/data/The_Beatles.json

OData: http://dbpedia.org/data/The_Beatles.jsod

Microdata: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Beatles%3E&output=application%2Fmicrodata%2Bjson

JSON-LD: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Beatles%3E&output=application%2Fld%2Bjson

Comment: I can download data dumps containing title and small abstracts from here directly: http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38 and this is the format: http://downloads.dbpedia.org/preview.php?file=3.8_sl_en_sl_short_abstracts_en.ttl.bz2 Now can you can help me in processing this ttl file? Actually that SPARQL query editor had some rate limits and this seems a better option to me. Now processing TTL file is the thing

Comment: @stalin Some of the past answers in these topics have described how to download TTL files, load them into a local SPARQL endpoint, and query them.  For instance, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16610663/1281433) (in the section **Using TDB Locally**) sets up an endpoint for some data downloaded from a UK source, but would work just as well for data from DBpedia.